# ffmpeg zscale error on Freebsd

Tags: ffmpeg, installation, freebsd

Installed via: `pkg install ffmpeg`

When I run an ffmpeg command with zscale, I get the error: `No such filter: 'zscale'`

Can someone point me to directions for compiling with `libzimg` to get around this problem?  The Windows installer just includes the library by default, and googling has brought me no help on figuring out how to install the libzimg library with freebsd.

Comment: Did you compile ffmpeg with `--enable-libzimg`?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm new to FreeBSD, and I have no doubt that there is a more efficient way to do this.  This is what worked for me, but I would welcome someone posting a "better" solution.*

My problem was figuring out how to do the compilation manually on a FreeBSD system.  For anyone else with the same problem...

1. `portsnap fetch`    # Update the repository from Fresh Ports
2. `portsnap extract`  # Grab the source code
3. `cd /usr/ports/ffmpeg` # Go to the ffmpeg source code folder
4. `make install clean` # Build the code

When you execute #4, you'll get a screen to select compilation options for ffmpeg.  Find the libzimg option and add it to the compilation.

All the dependencies will also need to build, and they will also give you a screen to select options.  That gets tedious, so to skip all the prompts you can do: `make install clean BATCH="YES"`.